# Web Application Project URL - from EnvDTE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automation, envdte

Is it possible to get the URL for a web application project from the EnvDTE Project object?

i.e. I want the URL I see in Visual Studio when I look at the Web tab in Project properties.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to retrieve it if the project is set to either "Use Visual Studio Development Server", or "Use Local IIS Server"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the [`Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.project.properties.aspx) collection of the [`Project`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.project%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) object you've got? As per [this post](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Threads/Single.aspx/asp-net-web-controls/1731?ArtId=YwAOb.13947%24i4.10235@newsread1.news.atl.earthlink.net) a [`ProjectItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.projectitem.aspx) has an "URL" item in there, so the `Project` might have one too ...

I admit this is just a guess since I know absolutely nothing about webapps, I'm just digging through EnvDte stuff myself right now. But maybe it helps ...

Comment: I suspect it's in there somewhere :) I'll mark this as the answer for now... Thanks!